# UIButton in TableViewCell Calls 2 Functions

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

Even after completely rewriting this view controller I'm still getting an issue with 2 buttons in the last 2 sections of my table view. I have 2 buttons, one of them in section 3 the other in section 4 (the tableview is only 5 sections so these are the last 2) both of these buttons have a similar function when clicked they add 1 extra item to the section. The problem is when I click one of these buttons it works fine until I select the other (which aren't in anyway connected other than the fact their in the same tableview) when I click on the other it adds 1 to its section like it's supposed to then will add 1 to the other section. I've tried checking the number of targets to see if maybe its adding the functions for both buttons to a single one of them but even though I only have one target both functions are still called... Ive tried just about everything I can think of any help would be greatly appreciated (Sorry for not posting any code its a pretty complex swift file let me know what you would like to see and I will edit this answer).

EDIT - This is what I give for section 4 of the UITableViews cellForRowAt (section 3 and section 4 in cellForRowAt are identical other than some naming differences)

```
} else {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Section Card", for: indexPath)
            let positionsSectionCard = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

            positionsSectionCard.text = "Positions"
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Picker Cell", for: indexPath)
            let positionPicker = cell.contentView.subviews[0].subviews[1].subviews[0] as! UIPickerView
            let addPositionButton = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(4) as! UIButton
            let positionList = Array(positions.keys).sorted()
            var positionCounter = 0
            var enabledPositionsCounter = 0

            positionPicker.dataSource = self
            positionPicker.delegate = self

            while positionCounter < positionList.count {
                if positions[positionList[positionCounter]]! {
                    enabledPositionsCounter = enabledPositionsCounter + 1
                }
                positionCounter = positionCounter + 1
            }

            if enabledPositionsCounter == positions.count {
                addPositionButton.isEnabled = false
                addPositionButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: .normal)
            } else {
                addPositionButton.isEnabled = true
                addPositionButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
            }

            addPositionButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
            addPositionButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
            addPositionButton.setTitle("Add\nPosition", for: .normal)
            addPositionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addPosition), for: .touchUpInside)
        } else {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Item Card", for: indexPath)
            let positionLabel = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
            let removePositionButton = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton
            let positionList = Array(positions.keys).sorted()
            var positionCounter = 0
            var usedPositionsList: [String] = []

            positionLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            positionLabel.numberOfLines = 2

            if eventSettingsTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 4) < 4 {
                while positionCounter < positionList.count {
                    if positions[positionList[positionCounter]]! {
                        positionLabel.text = positionList[positionCounter]
                    }
                    positionCounter = positionCounter + 1
                }
            } else {

                while positionCounter < eventSettingsTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 4) {
                    if eventSettingsTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: positionCounter + 2, section: 4))?.contentView.subviews[0].subviews[1].subviews[0] != nil {
                        print((eventSettingsTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: positionCounter + 2, section: 4))?.contentView.subviews[0].subviews[1].subviews[0] as! UILabel).text!)
                        usedPositionsList.append((eventSettingsTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: positionCounter + 2, section: 4))?.contentView.subviews[0].subviews[1].subviews[0] as! UILabel).text!)
                    }
                    positionCounter = positionCounter + 1
                }

                positionCounter = 0

                while positionCounter < positionList.count {
                    if !usedPositionsList.contains(positionList[positionCounter]) && positions[positionList[positionCounter]]! {
                    positionLabel.text = positionList[positionCounter]
                    }
                    positionCounter = positionCounter + 1
                }

            removePositionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removePosition(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell without more information. Post your `cellForRow(at:)` method, and also show a screenshot of the connections inspector for your table view cell if you've set up a cell prototype in IB. (It IS possible to have multiple  IBActions linked to a button, and that sounds like a good guess as to what's going wrong.)

Comment: @DuncanC I just edited the question please let me know if this isn't enough or you need some clarification on something

Comment: You're adding `self` as target to button multiple times here:             `removePositionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removePosition(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)` When you add target to buttons, it doesn't remove previously added targets. You need to remove previous targets.

Comment: @AdilSoomro Before posting this I've checked the number of targets and I'm always given 1 per button (assuming its giving me an incorrect value) is there any way to quickly remove all targets on the button?

Comment: Yes, UIButton has remove target method, passing `nil` as param would remove all targets. `button.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)`

Comment: @AdilSoomro That Worked!!! Thank you so much (not sure why it was giving me an incorrect value though kinda weird)

Comment: xV, see my answer. I explain why you're not getting the answer you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A table view reuses cells. Basically, as the cell leaves the screen, it gets reused as one entering the screen (if they have the same reuse identifier). `table​View(_:​cell​For​Row​At:​)` is called multiple times whenever the table view needs a cell. It can even be called multiple times for the same cell (like if it leaves the visual field and then re-enters).

This line, or others like it, are adding multiple targets to the same button which already as it's previous targets you added when the cell was used somewhere else in the table view.

```
removePositionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removePosition(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

What you may need to do is remove the targets before adding new ones or remove the `addTarget` calls from `table​View(_:​cell​For​Row​At:​)`.

Check out the documentation for [`UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol) to see how you can remove targets.

*Hint: [`remove​Target(_:​action:​for:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol/1618248-removetarget)

Comment: If I were to check removePositionButton.allTargets would it give me the correct number of current targets? (I've checked allTargets and it only shows me 1)

Answer (score 1):

If you use

`button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(action1(_:)))`

and then

`button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(action2(_:)))`

You'll have 2 actions associated with your button, but only 1 target. You've added 2 actions for the same target. Thus the `allTargets` property will still show 1 target even though there are 2 target/actions connected to the button.

If you've added multiple actions with the same target and same control event, you should use `actions(forTarget:forControlEvent:)` to find them. (in your case, `actions(forTarget: self, forControlEvent:, .touchUpInside)`)

In your `cellForRow(at:)` method, you should either check the number of targets /actions on your button and only add a new target/action to the button if the actions count is zero, or remove all target/actions before adding new ones.

The rule of thumb here is that cells get recycled, and you should always assume that a cell returned `cellForRow(at:)` has settings leftover from the last time it was used, and that you must fully configure every view in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your button is (mistakenly) linked to multiple actions?

[image]